# Sass compiler can not find valo import in vaadin project

Tags: maven, gulp, vaadin, vaadin7, saas

I would like to compile `sass` files in `vaadin` project using `gulp`. I have created for that a project using `maven`. I use `gulp` to have auto compile and live reload when i work with `sass`

The `sass` compile works fine, my problem is the valo import:

```
 @import "../valo/valo.scss";
```

I couldn't find this file anywhere in maven project. With this import, i can not the `gulp`compiler because he doesn't find the file, and without it, i can not compile and install the project.

Anyone have idea how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Does the `../valo/valo.scss` exists (Seen relative from your scss file)?

Comment: It doesn't exist, but i think it would be generated when the project is builded with maven

Comment: No, the valo.scss is included in the `vaadin-themes-7.6.3.jar`file. The sass build process somehow adds this to the search path, so it can be used to inherit from it. So you probably have to do something similar for your `gulp`processing

Comment: Do you solved your problem ?